# For Azure DevOps "pipelines" resource, what is the intended use and set-up of "resources: pipelines: pipeline: tags:"?

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-yaml-pipelines

We are trying to figure out what is the intended use/behavior/set-up of tags defined in the Azure DepOs docs [Define a pipelines resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#define-a-pipelines-resource).

We have a build pipeline that has the following task at the very end, adding the Deployable-Artifact tag to builds that produce an artifact.

```
- script: echo "##vso[build.addbuildtag]Deployable-Artifact"
  condition: and(succeeded(), not(in(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest', 'Schedule')))
```

We are in the process of converting our classic build and releases to pipelines, so when we read the docs

```
tags: [ string ] # list of tags required on the pipeline to pickup default artifacts, optional; Used only for manual or scheduled triggers
```

and then configure our release pipeline as follows:

```
trigger: none
pr: none
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: API-Deployment 
    source: API-Build
    tags: 
    - Deployable-Artifact   
    trigger: 
      branches:
        include: 
        - refs/heads/main
```

we are expecting it to filter the builds available to the release resources similar to what we were able to do with build tags in classic releases. However, as per our condition above, we are not expecting to see any PR builds or failed builds in the following Resources selector ui for manually triggering the releases, but they are there

[image]

[The answer found here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/How-to-prevent-a-YAML-Deployment-Pipelin/1667940#T-N1674331) suggests that "resources: pipelines: pipeline: tags:" should be a build tag while "resources: pipelines: pipeline: trigger: tags:" should be a repo tag.  If this is true, it would be very helpful to indicate that in the documentation.

What behavior should we expect when adding a build tag to "resources: pipelines: pipeline: tags:"?

Comment: Hello there, I don't get what you mean by "Do you have any information about the UI?", could you please tell me where the screenshot in your question comes from? How can I see this page?

Comment: Facing the same problem. Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

> What behavior should we expect when adding a build tag to "resources: pipelines: pipeline: tags:"?

If a pipeline is triggered by another pipeline, then, of course, it will choose the build that triggers it as its resource.

If a pipeline is triggered manually or scheduled:

1. The pipeline will **choose the latest build** as its resource if **tag is not set**.
2. The pipeline will **choose the latest build that meets tag** as its resource if **tag is set**.

Comment: thank you for your help @Jane Ma-MSFT!  Do you have any information about the UI?  Because when I open it, by default it selects the most recent build even if it is a PR Build that doesn't have the expected build tag on it.

Comment: @cResults Hello there, I don't get what you mean, could you please tell me where the screenshot in your question comes from? How can I see this page?

Comment: for any pipeline that has a Resource Trigger click "Run pipeline", then "Resources", then open the resource associated with the triggering pipeline.